# Automate Access of Alpha Numerical index in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following kind of index while accessing json data using jquery

```
data.rows[0].student_1
data.rows[0].student_2
data.rows[0].student_3 and so on...
```

Now, i want to automate this thing in a loop like

```
for(var i=1;i<length;i++)
{
  // so that i can access all student records i.e. student_1, student_2 and so on
 data.rows[0].student_+i; // this doesn't work

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square brackets:

```
for(var i=1;i<length;i++)
{
 data.rows[0]['student_'+i];
}
```

see also here: http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval

Answer (score 1):

Use the array style property accessor:

```
data.rows[0]["student_"+i];
```